What is the dataflow usage permission for data model and report developers?
Suppose I create a dataflow inside of a new workspace, what is the minimum permission that I need to assign my data model developers so that they can utilise this data flow in the same or another workspace?
When the data model developers create data models in various workspaces, by utilising the above data flow, then what permission does the end user of report require on the data flow? Or is data model permission sufficient?
